# Null conditional operator and void methods

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, null-conditional-operator

Before C# 6, I would write code to dispose of an object like:

```
if (_odbcConnection != null)
{
    _odbcConnection.Close();
    _odbcConnection.Dispose();
    _odbcConnection = null;
}
```

With 6, I can write much less code:

```
_odbcConnection?.Close();
_odbcConnection?.Dispose();
_odbcConnection = null;
```

But are the two equivalent?

Comment: Run the code that you've already written and see for yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your two lower examples are *almost* equal. But the second block

```
_odbcConnection?.Close();
_odbcConnection?.Dispose();
_odbcConnection = null;
```

will be translated by the compiler to something like

```
var tmp1 = _odbcConnection;
if (tmp1 != null) tmp1.Close();
var tmp2 = _odbcConnection;
if (tmp2 != null) tmp2.Dispose();
_odbcConnection = null;
```

This means that this version is thread-safe, while the first (with the outer `if` clause) is not. If some mysterious thread would set `_odbcConnection` to `null` after the `if` but before `Close()` or `Dispose()`, a `NullReferenceException` would be thrown.

By using the null-conditional-operator you avoid this problem, because the reference is first stored in a compiler generated variable and then checked and used.

---

The above translation only applies to fields and properties. For local variables (only in scope of a single method, e.g. method parameters), this translation is not necessary and the code ends up like

```
if (_odbcConnection != null) _odbcConnection.Dispose();
```

That is because local variables cannot be changed by different threads.

And of course this is only the generated C#. In IL you may not see this anymore as it is either optimized away or obsolete, because in IL the reference value is loaded into a register and then compared. Again, another thread can no longer change that value in the register. So on IL level this discussion is somewhat pointless.

Comment: is this translation documented somewhere? because I can't prove it by looking at the generated IL code

Comment: @SelmanGenç for local variables there will be no extra compiler generated `tmp`, because it's not possible that any other thread can access local variables. So my example translation only applies to fields or properties. I checked it with dotPeek. Check the _decompiled sources_, not the IL. The IL may completely ommit this as it loads the value into registers and therefor does not need extra variables anymore. It may be optimized away.